# Swift 3: Try to convert matrix_float3x3 to SCNVector3

Tags: swift, swift3, gameplay-kit

I'm trying to make a 3D game in Swift.  I want my enemy to follow a path using a **GKGoal**.  The **GKAgent3D** has a **rotation** property type **matrix_float3x3**, but the **SCNNode's rotation** property is type **SCNVector4**.

How can I convert **matrix_float3x3** to **SCNVector4** using simple swift?

I already search the web, but there is almost none documentation about using GameplayKit with SceneKit, or the GKAgent3D.

I found some math documentation and functions for matrix rotations and angles (for example: [Decomposing and composing a 3×3 rotation matrix](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846)), but this returns me the XYZ angles for a SNVector3, not SNVector4.

Comment: You need no greetings (and excuse your English), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635578/converting-matrix-float3x3-rotation-to-scenekit/46373613#46373613