# Converting matrix_float3x3 rotation to SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

I was experimenting with GameplayKit’s GKAgent3D class to move a SCNNode within a scene. I was able to update the SCNNode with the agent’s position, but not rotation. The issue being the agent’s rotation is stored as a matrix_float3x3, which doesn’t match any of data types SceneKit uses for storing rotational information.

So what I’d like to know is if there’s a simple function or method that could convert a rotation stored as matrix_float3x3 to any SceneKit data types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on @rickster 's answer, here's a nice way to take the top-left 3x3 of a 4x4 matrix in Swift, taking advantage of the expanded simd support in the iOS 11/ tvOS 11/ High Sierra version of SceneKit:

```
extension float4 {
    var xyz: float3 {
        return float3(x, y, z)
    }

    init(_ vec3: float3, _ w: Float) {
        self = float4(vec3.x, vec3.y, vec3.z, w)
    }
}

extension float4x4 {
    var upperLeft3x3: float3x3 {
        let (a,b,c,_) = columns
        return float3x3(a.xyz, b.xyz, c.xyz)
    }

    init(rotation: float3x3, position: float3) {
        let (a,b,c) = rotation.columns
        self = float4x4(float4(a, 0),
                        float4(b, 0),
                        float4(c, 0),
                        float4(position, 1))
    }
}
```

Then, to update your agent to match your node's orientation, you'd write:

```
agent.rotation = node.simdTransform.upperLeft3x3
```

Or, if the node in question is not at the "root" level (as in, a direct child of the rootNode), you might want to use the node's worldTransform:

```
agent.rotation = node.simdWorldTransform.upperLeft3x3
```

EDIT: If the node in question has a dynamic physics body attached, or is being animated with an SCNTransaction block, the node's presentation node will more accurately reflect its current position on screen:

```
agent.position = node.presentation.simdWorldPosition
agent.rotation = node.presentation.simdWorldTransform.upperLeft3x3
```

EDIT: added code above for going in the other direction, moving the node to match the agent.

```
node.simdTransform = float4x4(rotation: agent3d.rotation, position: agent3d.position)
```

Note that if you have a physics body attached to the node, it should be `kinematic` rather than `dynamic` if you're going to be directly modifying the node's transform in this way.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, very helpful! That code is so much cleaner than what I came up with.

Comment: Agreed, this is really helpful.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can anyone comment on why some of this stuff isn't in the Docs, or where does one go to learn that this is how you are supposed to do things...

Answer (score 5):

SceneKit takes transform matrices as `SCNMatrix4`, and provides utilities for converting from SIMD `matrix_float4x4`: `init(_ m: float4x4)` for Swift and `SCNMatrix4FromMat4` for ObjC/C++.

Sadly, I don't see a built-in way to convert between SIMD 3x3 and 4x4 matrices using the assumption that the 3x3 is the upper left of the 4x4. (Seems like you'd expect that in the SIMD library, so it's worth [filing a bug to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) about.)

But it's not too hard to provide one yourself: just construct a 4x4 from column vectors, using the three column vectors of the 3x3 (padded out to `float4` vectors with zero for the `w` component) and identity for the fourth column (`0,0,0,1`). (Implementation code left for the reader, partly because I don't want to write it for three languages.) After converting `float3x3` to `float4x4` you can convert to `SCNMatrix4`.

---

**Edit:** In iOS 11 / tvOS 11 / macOS 10.13 (why didn't they just call this year's macOS version 11, too?), SceneKit has a whole parallel set of APIs for using SIMD types like `float4x4` directly; e.g. `simdTransform`. However, you still need to convert a 3x3 to a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Thank you Rickster, I really appreciate your thorough answer it was very helpful to me. At least now I know what I need to do, I was searching through simd and other libraries, just hoping that perhaps I just overlooked a method/function. Just one last thing, I've seen your other answers to various questions, you are a freaking wizard, I hope to be as knowledgable as you one day. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Ryan sorry about the late reply, I don't have any sample code on hand, but if you have a specific question about implementation please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update Rickster, so glad they added SIMD types, I'm really looking forward to using them 8).